# Looking for encoding of SVG data

Tags: encryption, encodings, strings

I have some SVG images stored in a database; but I am not able to find out which encoding is used.

Unfortunately, I don't have the exact SVG plain text available. The given examples "probably" start with `<svg>` or an XML header like `<?xml version="1.0"`...

Some examples (shortened):

```
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 ...
```

```
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 ...
```

Since both examples start with the same prefix I assume that no encryption is applied. Maybe the data is compressed? Obviously the string contains only hex values - but I did not find a way to extract a meaningful SVG-Image from that.

Any help or ideas? What are possible next steps to find out more about the encoding?

Best regards
Dominik

Comment: How did you generate the svgs? Did you have access to program that is able to read them?

Comment: Unfortunately, the program that decodes the SVG is a pretty complicated native UWP application. I have access to it and tried to disassemble it.
I can see that the app access the database and reads the given string, but after that it gets too complicated for me. Using APIMonitor I found the calls to the sqlite library. Having activated all API calls from the Security / encryption categories in APIMonitor I can see no further calls there, but this might be misleading.
So I thought maybe its a common decoding that is understandable without disassembling.
Any further ideas?

Comment: How do you know they are SVGs?  Can you post 10 or 20 complete files? Are there other fields associated with these records in the database?